# Sort DataGridViewImage Column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to be able to sort a `DataGridViewImageColumn` by **clicking on its header**. I set the *sort mode to automatic* in the designer, but when I click on the header nothing happens.

Are these columns sortable?

If so, what do I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did an example showing how to *sort a dataGridView* by using a **custom comparer class**. As @Andrew Morton posted there are some ressources on the net, that may be helpful

1. [Sorting a dataGridView image Column](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?559639-RESOLVED-Sorting-a-DataGridView-image-column)
2. [Sorting DGV image Column](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/Vsexpressvcs/thread/B7CC00A4-14B6-4461-A812-D700507BA786)
3. [DataGridView.Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)
4. [ColumHeaderCell.SortingGlyphDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell.sortglyphdirection.aspx)

Personally I looked into 1./3. and 4. combined them all and here we are. I tested it with two pics (100x100 and 200x200px) and sorted by width. Of course you may change this to whatever you want.

First I created a form `frmImateColumnSort.vb`

```
Dim colName As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Dim colImage As New DataGridViewImageColumn

Private Sub frmImageColumnSort_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' create columns (or create them with designer)
    colName.Name = "colName"
    colName.HeaderText = "Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colName)

    colImage.Name = "colImage"
    colImage.HeaderText = "Image"
    ' we are going to set sortMode in source 
    ' so we can show a sortGlyph
    colImage.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colImage)

    ' add some demo data
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("imageA", Image.FromFile("imageA.jpg"))
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("imageB", Image.FromFile("imageB.jpg"))
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    ' in case imageColumnHeader is clicked
    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = colImage.Name Then
        ' show correct sortingGlyph
        Dim currentSortOrder = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection
        If currentSortOrder = SortOrder.None OrElse currentSortOrder = SortOrder.Descending Then
            currentSortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending
        Else
            currentSortOrder = SortOrder.Descending
        End If
        DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = currentSortOrder
        ' use a custom comparerClass to provide sorting abilities for images
        DataGridView1.Sort(New ImageComparer(currentSortOrder))
    End If
End Sub
```

Afterwards I created an `ImageComparer.vb` class and implemented `IComparer`.

```
Public Class ImageComparer
  Implements System.Collections.IComparer

  Private sortOrderModifier As Integer = 1

  Public Sub New(ByVal sortOrder As SortOrder)
    If sortOrder = sortOrder.Descending Then
        sortOrderModifier = -1
    ElseIf sortOrder = sortOrder.Ascending Then
        sortOrderModifier = 1
    End If
  End Sub

  Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer _
    Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare

    Dim DataGridViewRow1 As DataGridViewRow = CType(x, DataGridViewRow)
    Dim DataGridViewRow2 As DataGridViewRow = CType(y, DataGridViewRow)

    ' sort according to eg. Width by accessing column 1 - containing the image
    ' you may access any cell here. You might even sort imageColumn on any other colum
    Dim img1 As Image = CType(DataGridViewRow1.Cells(1).Value, Image)
    Dim img2 As Image = CType(DataGridViewRow2.Cells(1).Value, Image)
    Dim CompareResult As Integer = img1.Width.CompareTo(img2.Width)

    Return CompareResult * sortOrderModifier
  End Function
End Class
```

This results in following screenshots

[image: sortState1]
[image: sortState2]

In case you are working with a dataSource bound to your dataGridView, you will have to sort your DataSource! Eg. *[Sorting a dataTable image column q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879635/c-sharp-window-form-datatable-with-image-column-sorting)*

hth

Answer (score 1):

You're meant to do some research (e.g. a search on google) before asking here.

You would have found things like http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?559639-RESOLVED-Sorting-a-DataGridView-image-column.